# what do i do to get real time update from mysql to elasticsearch

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I've created a feeder script based on: https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-jdbc/wiki/jdbc-plugin-feeder-mode-as-an-alternative-to-the-deprecated-elasticsearch-river-api

I've not added any new attributes to the above example (ofcourse changed the DB settings etc). The table is indexed quite rapidly and then the feeder script terminates gracefully. What do i need to do make the feeder script persistent and get the updates from mysql db in (near) real time as and when a new record is added to the db?

Thank you

**UPDATE:**

The elastic search version is 1.4.4 with plugins river and head installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for the interest.

I finally decided to create the document both in DB and in ES. I'm refreshing the index before i get any value in the new doc (after the doc creation in the index). I know this is not an "ideal" situation but fixes my problem for now.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options to get a near realtime behavior, but it comes with some cost.

1. Trigger index refresh explicitly

Could be done after all data has been written.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-refresh.html

2. Configure index refresh time

You can set the index refresh tie to a short time span.

```
{
  "settings": {
    "refresh_interval": "1s" 
  }
}
```

For more information see: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/near-real-time.html

Comment: I dont think this is  the answer OP is looking for, OP wants to _sync_ mysql and ES in real time, `refresh interval` is period between documents getting indexed and then those documents actually becoming **searchable**, and by default it is `1s`